# My application doesn't open after trying to implement iAds!

Tags: iphone, iad

I have been trying to implement iAds into my application, but this is what happens:

1.Tap on app
2.Loading Screen Displayed for a few seconds
3.App Crashes

This is whats returned:

> 2010-11-06 20:19:11.043 Vampire Quiz
>   Final[99722:207] Unknown class
>   AdViewController in Interface Builder
>   file. 2010-11-06 20:19:11.066 Vampire
>   Quiz Final[99722:207]
>   -[Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController setBannerIsVisible:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x761c710
>   2010-11-06 20:19:11.409 Vampire Quiz
>   Final[99722:207] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>
> reason:
>   '-[Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController
>   setBannerIsVisible:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x761c710'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x02a88b99 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x02bd840e objc_exception_throw + 47 
>   2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x02a8a6ab -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x029fa2b6 __*forwarding*** + 966  4
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x029f9e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50 
>   5   Vampire Quiz Final
>   0x000027a2
>   -[Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController viewDidLoad] + 601  6   UIKit
>   0x003715ca -[UIViewController view] +
>   179  7   Vampire Quiz Final
>   0x000021b1
>   -[Vampire_Quiz_FinalAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]
>   + 74  8   UIKit                               0x002c7f27 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:]
>   + 1163  9   UIKit                               0x002ca3b0 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
>   + 346  10  UIKit                               0x002d43ec -[UIApplication
>   handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958  11 
>   UIKit
>   0x002ccb3c -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>   + 71  12  UIKit                               0x002d19bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent +
>   7672  13  GraphicsServices
>   0x03368822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550 
>   14  CoreFoundation
>   0x02a69ff4
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  15  CoreFoundation                      0x029ca807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215 
>   16  CoreFoundation
>   0x029c7a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979  17 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x029c7350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208 
>   18  CoreFoundation
>   0x029c7271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97  19
>   UIKit
>   0x002c9c6d -[UIApplication _run] + 625
>   20  UIKit
>   0x002d5af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160 
>   21  Vampire Quiz Final
>   0x00002144 main + 102  22  Vampire
>   Quiz Final                  0x000020d5
>   start + 53 ) terminate called after
>   throwing an instance of 'NSException'
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   (gdb)

P.S. I am new to development on the iPhone

Thanks

This is my code :

```
@implementation Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController

- (IBAction)V;

{

    Vork *V = [[Vork alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:V animated:NO];

}
- (IBAction)A;

{

    About *A = [[About alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:A animated:NO];

}
- (IBAction)I;

{

    Instructions *I = [[Instructions alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:I animated:NO];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);

    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];

    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    adView.delegate=self;

    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner

{

    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)

    {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px

        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 50);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;

    }

}



- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error

{

    if (self.bannerIsVisible)

    {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue

        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

    }

}



@end
```

How can I fix it???

Answer (score 1):

you are using `self.bannerIsVisible` but I can't see neither a synthesize for this nor setters and getters. Did you made a property with `bannerIsVisible` in your .h file?

To resolve this crash you should define the property in you header and add a @synthesize statement in your implementation.

---

Maybe you should start with something more basic to get to know the fundamental things like properties, synthesizers, compiler warnings (there should be one), debugging, and so on.
I don't want to be rude, but you won't learn much by using copied code you don't understand.

Comment: Yes I have made a property in my .h file

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>;

@interface Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

{

 ADBannerView *adView;

 BOOL bannerIsVisible;

}

@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;

-(IBAction)V;
-(IBAction)A;
-(IBAction)I;

@end

Comment: if the property is there you should add `@synthesize bannerIsVisible;` below `@implementation Vampire_Quiz_FinalViewController`. The compiler should give you a warning because this is missing.

Answer (score 0):

unrecognized selector sent to instance: this means the method for that class is not found. Check the class implementation.